# Cloud instances multiple vs single with longer time cost analysis

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, multiple-instances

I am trying to compare the cost of running the same machine, same load on GCP( I don't know if the answer would be valid for other providers).
so does running the same instance for x amount of time (10 hours for example) cost the same as running 10 instances for one hour?

Comment: In general, one instance will be cheaper when you factor in the cost of storage. Use a pricing calculator to determine actual costs.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would be the same as Google Cloud charges you for the resouces that you allocate on your project which has a fixed price you can use this [Compute Engine pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing) documentation as reference and also you can use the [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) for the detailed cost breakdown of your instance, as @John Hanley suggested.